# Android socket server with multiple clients.. Hopefully close, but no cigar

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm attempting to create a socket server on Android which is capable of handling multiple client connections. Each of these client connections supports asynchronous communication. I think I have my implementation close, but I'm running into issues..

The server app launches a `ConnectionListener` object on it's `onCreate`. This object is an `AsyncTask` object which creates the `SocketServer` and then loops while listening for a client connection. When it gets a connection, it launches another `AsyncTask` object, `SocketConnectionManager`, and continues to listen for other client connections.

The `SocketConnectionManager` creates two additional `AsycTasks` -- One for input, `ListenAsyncTask`; and one for output, `MessageAsyncTask`.

`ListenAsyncTask` creates a `BufferedReader` from the client socket, and loops around `readLine()`, always looking for input from the client socket.

`MessageAsyncTask` waits for messages that need to be pushed to the client, and the pushes the messages to the client.

I'm using a **custom thread executor** for all the async tasks, which I think avoids potential problems with long running asnyc tasks.

Everything works as expected with one client. When two clients join things begin to look look good, but eventually only the most recently connected client's messages will ever get through to the `ListenAsyncTask`.

One of the things I'm tempted to do is refactor to use `Threads` instead of `AsnycTasks`. I thought I wouldn't have to do this when using the `executor` -- With the custom `executor` I seem to be able to get all the tasks to run concurrently.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it. The code is below.

```
public class ConnectionListener extends AsyncTask<String,Socket,String> {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;



    private Context context;
    private GameState gameState;
    int idCounter;
    private String TAG = "Connection Listener";
    private ArrayList<SocketConnectionManager> socketConnections;

    public ConnectionListener(Context context, ServerSocket serverSocket){
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        idCounter = 0;
        socketConnections = new ArrayList<SocketConnectionManager>();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = "";

        Log.i(TAG, "Start listening for connections");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Still Looking");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                Log.i(TAG, "Connection Found");
                publishProgress(new Socket[] {clientSocket});
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Socket... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i(TAG, "start socket connection");
        idCounter++;
        SocketConnectionManager socketConectionManager = new SocketConnectionManager(context,values[0],String.valueOf(idCounter));
        Log.i(TAG, "about to execute");
        socketConectionManager.executeOnExecutor(((FireTvApplication) context).threadPoolExecutor, (String[])null);
        Log.i(TAG, "executed");
        socketConnections.add(socketConectionManager);
     }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    }
}
```

SocketConnectionManager:

```
public class SocketConnectionManager extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    private Context context;
    private MessageAsyncTask messageAsyncTask;
    private ListenAsyncTask listenAsyncTask;
    private String ipAddress;
    private Socket socket;
    private String id;

    public SocketConnectionManager(Context context, Socket socket, String id){
        this.context = context;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.id = id;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("SocketConnetionManger", "start background task");

        startConnection();
        return "";
    }
    public void startConnection(){
        Log.i("SocketConnetionManger", "start connection");

        try{
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader  bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
            Log.i("SocketConnetionManger", "waiting to read line");
            String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(response == null){
                 Log.i("SocketConnetionManger","null line read - just ip test from client");
             }
            else{
                 Log.i("SocketConnetionManger","message read:" + response);
                 messageAsyncTask = new MessageAsyncTask(context,socket,id);
                 listenAsyncTask = new ListenAsyncTask(context,socket,id);
                 messageAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(((FireTvApplication) context).threadPoolExecutor, (String[])null);
                 listenAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(((FireTvApplication) context).threadPoolExecutor, (String[])null);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

ListenAsyncTask:

```
public class ListenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    private Socket client;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private Context context;    
    private String id;
    private String TAG = "ListenAsyncTask";

    public ListenAsyncTask(Context context, Socket socket, String id){
        client = socket;
        this.context = context;
        this.id =id;

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = "";
        Log.i(TAG + id, "background task started");
        try {
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
            while (true)
            {
                response = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(response == null){
                    Log.i(TAG + id,"null line read");
                    break;
                }
                Log.i(TAG + id,"message read:" + response);
                JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(response);
                messageJson.put("id",id);
                publishProgress(new String[]{messageJson.toString()});
                Log.i(TAG + id, "message posted");
            }
            Log.i(TAG + id, "connection ended");
            inputStreamReader.close();
            client.close();   //closing the connection

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i(TAG + id,"sending received intent -" + values[0]);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.excelltech.tft.server.received");
        intent.putExtra("message",values[0]);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.i(TAG + id,"ENDED");

    }


}
```

The client code that writes to the server is below. The logs indicate that the writes seem to work correctly, but after a couple writes, only the last client to connect to the server actually has its messages received by the server.

```
        while (connectionEstablished){

            while(waitingForProcessing){

            }
            waitingForProcessing = true;
            String outputMessage = responseString;
            Log.i("MessageAsyncTask", "about to send message:" + outputMessage);
            printwriter.write(outputMessage + "\n");  //write the message to output stream
            printwriter.flush();
            Log.i("MessageAsyncTask", "message sent");
        }
```

Comment: when that happens, have you looked in the debugger if the other threads are alive and running?

Comment: Hmmm good suggestion.. The threads are all alive, but it does look like one changes to MONITOR when this is happening. MONITOR appears to be the code for when the thread is blocked due to trying to obtain a lock on an object. Still not quite sure what's causing the blocking, but it's a good lead.

Comment: I'd like to be of more help, but haven't done much stuff with threads in Android. So I just send some positive vibes and wish you good luck with the debugger !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by moving the creation of the BufferedReader in ListenAsyncTask inside the while loop.

Comment: That seems a little odd.

Comment: I agree.. it doesn't seem to jive with most the java socket examples I've seen. I'll explore further tonight to make sure I'm not leaking memory every loop around. I thought I'd try to close the buffered reader at the end of the while loop so that there was always one close per buffered reader, but this causes the entire socket to come down.

Comment: Also, in the code I posted above I'm creating a buffered reader in SocketConnectionManager as well as in ListenAsyncTask. I've tried passing the buffered reader created in SocketConnectionManager to ListenAsyncTask, thus eliminating the creation of a second buffered reader, but I still get the same blocking behavior on the thread.